# Catching exceptions while running git commands in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have just started leaning Git and Powershell and trying to create a not complex PS script to sync a branch from Git.

I want to catch possible exceptions that can occur during execution of git commands in powershell.

Here is an extract from my code, where I try to use a standard try/catch approach:

```
try { git reset --hard origin/master }
    catch  {

                LogMessage ("Failure on syncing files from the GitHub")
                LogMessage $_.Exception.Message;
                Return

            }
```

LogMessage is a function to output exceptions in a file. I use the Posh-Git to run the script.

For some reasons this doesn't work. Exceptions are not gathered by the catch, return command is not executed and the script still running.

What I have missed?

Thanks in advance and have a good day.

Comment: Well, have you verified that your script actually *does* get into the catch block at all, e.g. by printing a simple message to the console or something similar?

Comment: Set erroraction to stop.

Comment: Yes, I checked that the script doesn't get into the catch block while exceptions happen. Looks like git exceptions are not handled by PowerShell.

Comment: As for the ErrorAction parameter - looks like the parameter is actual for PowerShell commands, but not for Git commands. When I try to run with the ErrorAction parameter script fails with - "git : error: unknown switch `E'"

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the return code from the git executable and raise Exceptions if you wish (but why would you?!)

Try checking the `$LASTEXITCODE` varialbe after running git. It should be 0 for success or a different number for different errors otherwise.

Comment: Yes, the approach to use the LASTEXITCODE works if I run git as an external process.  Below is an extract of code. But the $_.Exception.Message variable is not populated with exception messages that Git returns. I can logging git exception separately by Git functionality and log exceptions in the same file where PowerShell logs are stored, but I'm looking for better way (if exists). Anyway, thanks for your response!

Comment: Here is the extract with LASTERRORCODE usage : 


cmd.exe /c git reset1 --hard origin/master > $FileName
       if( $LastExitCode -ne 0 ){
   LogMessage ("Failure on syncing files from GitHub")
            LogMessage $_;
            Return
        }